# Segmentation fault, fgets in while loop

Tags: c, linux, while-loop, fopen, fgets

I try to read in a file multiple times instead of just once.
While trying that I got alot of segementation faults. The part of the program with the while loop looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* General use buffer */
#define STRLEN 8196
char    string[STRLEN];


int lines = 1024;
char    **line;
int linemax;

int longest=0;


int main(){
int len,i;
int zwei = 1;
FILE * fp;
char    *s;
int debug =  0;
line=(char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * 1024);
do{
    if ( (fp = fopen("rhel7_160731_0606.nmon", "r")) == NULL) {
        perror("failed to open file");      

                perror("fopen");
        exit(75);
    }
printf("where is the problem1,3\n");
    for (i = 0; fgets(string, STRLEN, fp) != NULL; i++) {
        if (i >= lines) {
            lines += 1024;
            line = (char **)realloc((void *)line, sizeof(char *) * lines);
        }

        if (string[strlen(string)-1] == '\n')
            string[strlen(string)-1] = 0;
        if (string[strlen(string)-1] == '\r')
            string[strlen(string)-1] = 0;
        if (string[strlen(string)-1] == ' ')
            string[strlen(string)-1] = 0;
        if (string[strlen(string)-1] == ',')
            string[strlen(string)-1] = 0;
        len = strlen(string) + 1;

        if (len > longest)
            longest = len;
        s = malloc(len);
        strcpy(s, string);
        line[i] = (char *)s;
    }
    linemax = i;
    lines = i;

    if (debug)
        for (i = 0; i < linemax; i++)
            printf("line %d lastline %s\n", i, line[i-1]);

zwei++;

}while(zwei<4);

return 0;
}
```

It hangs nothing or ends with a segmentation fault.

Comment: what does your debugger say?

Comment: Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004009df in main () at test.c:53
53   line[i] = (char *)s;

Comment: which debugger is that?

Comment: So now this is what happens: 
 
#0  __lll_lock_wait_private ()
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
#1  0x00007ffff7a8924b in _IO_fgets (buf=0xeb2d50 "\002", n=8196, fp=0xea1c40)
    at iofgets.c:50
#2  0x000000000040a7f9 in main (argc=8, argv=0x7fffffffdf68)

It runs twice and then something goes wrong. Is it a Buffer overflow?

Comment: `} while(zwei>4);` is never true, so it cannot loop twice, it's not the cause but I wonder how much else is careless.

Comment: I see you edited that to `} while(zwei<4);` so it has become obvious this is not your actual code.

Comment: Segmentation fault is typically: opcache, xdebug. Disable both and see what happens

Comment: when calling the heap allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) in C, the returned type is `void*` so can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces as that is visible even with variable width fonts.  Never use tabs for indenting as each wordprocessor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set for personal preferences

Comment: regarding this line: `printf("line %d lastline %s\n", i, line[i-1]);`.  On the first pass through the loop, the expression: `i-1` will be -1.  this will result in accessing memory before the beginning of the array `line[]`,   This is undefined behavior and can/will lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: the code is opening the same file: `"rhel7_160731_0606.nmon"` 4 times, but not closing it inbetween the calls to `fopen()`.  Infact, the code is never closing the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have forgotten to allocate memory for `line`. It fails here: `line[i] = (char *)s`. I think you need to set `lines` to zero, since you reallocate `line` only if your iterator `i` gets grower than `lines`.
Also, fix this: `while(zwei > 4)` to `while(zwei < 4)`. And, you *need* to `free` the memory you allocate - because you store all the pointers in `line`, it is not going to be complicated - just one loop.

Comment: It's a global variable, therefore initialised to `0` or `NULL` which `realloc` can deal with. But that is a good catch.

Comment: @WeatherVane I mean, he tries to write data in `line[i]`, but `line`, as you correctly say, sets to `NULL` by default.

Comment: how do I free the memory?

Comment: I inserted this : 
line=(char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * 1024);

Comment: @bastel Using `free( line[i] )` in a single, say, `for` loop. I have dealt with it putting the following loop right before `while` statement: `for (i = 0; i < lines; i++){free( (void*) line[i] );}` But if you want to store all the lines until the end, you may need something more elaborate.

Comment: @bastel I don't think you need to `malloc` it first, just set `lines` to `0`, and, as WeatherVane noticed, realloc can deal with `NULL` and at the first time it will work as `malloc`

Comment: My actuall programm now runs twice before it hangs at this part of the code and it says : #0 __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95 #1 0x00007ffff7a8924b in _IO_fgets (buf=0xeb2d50 "\002", n=8196, fp=0xea1c40) at iofgets.c:50 #2 0x000000000040a7f9 in main (argc=8, argv=0x7fffffffdf68)  . What kind of error is this?

Comment: @bastel I don't know for sure, but what I also discovered, is that if the loop, that goes after `if(debug)`, you access `line[i-1]`, but the loop starts with `i = 0` - this causes `undefined behavior`